# Writing master-detail records to platform cache

Tags: apex, platform-cache

Platform Cache is very good feature for my development work. Today I came across a scenario which it doesn't work the way I intended. Perhaps someone can clarify that for me.

I have retrieved a master record and its child records using one SELECT and pushed that to Session cache with single put operation with master record Id as the key. When I retrieve it back from cache only master record is there, but not the child record, even though it was referenced in related list. I used the Cache.CacheBuilder for my convenience.

Has any of you came across this before?

Here's my code;

```
private class FeeStructureCache implements Cache.CacheBuilder {
    public Object doLoad(String feeStructId) {
        CDD_Membership_Fee__c feeStruc = [SELECT Name, EvaluationType__c, CalcType__c, Minimum_Fee__c, Discount__c, CPI__c,
                                                        (SELECT Discounted_Value__c, Lower_Limit__c, Upper_Limit__c, Rate__c, Value__c 
                                                           FROM Fee_Brackets__r
                                                          ORDER BY Lower_Limit__c)
                                                           FROM CDD_Membership_Fee__c
                                                          WHERE Id=:feeStructId];
        return feeStruc;    
    }
}

CDD_Membership_Fee__c feeStruc = (CDD_Membership_Fee__c) Cache.Session.get(FeeStructureCache.class, feeStrucId);
```